# PhpStorm shortcut to make caret go in between open and close php tags

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut, emmet

I started using PhpStorm some time ago and still couldn't find how to fix this issue.

Every time I type `php` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, it makes the entire open and close php tags (`<php ?>`), however, the cursor jumps to the end of the line (after the php closing tag).

How can I fix this shortcut to make the cursor/caret stay in between the tags?

Comment: 1) What is your PhpStorm version? 2) What file type that is? I've tried this in an empty `.php` file and it makes `<php></php>` for me instead... 3) Can you make a video/GIF that would show it in action (it may show so skipped nuances that can give a hint). 4) But speaking in general -- you can make a custom Live Template that can do what you want.

Comment: It is PhpStorm 2021.3 and I am using in a php file with content in it. I just need the caret to go in between the open and close php tags (<?php caret-here ?>) instead of jumping to the end (<?php  ?>caret-here)

Comment: As I have said -- it does not insert such a code for me. So the question here is where this functionality comes from. Could be some plugin or something else. That's why I've asked fro a video/GIF to see it in action.

Comment: This is my **custom** Live Template that can do what you want: https://i.imgur.com/pV2YD1X.png